# Markers from MapBox hosted map don't appear in TileMill

Tags: ios, mapbox, tilemill

I tried to load a custom map that i created in mapbox and import it to TileMill with tilemill-reference-layer. Although, markers don't appear in TileMill. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markers can be downloaded as GeoJSON or KML on https://www.mapbox.com/dashboard/. Click your project and then the filetype you prefer. Both can be uploaded to TileMill via the add layer interface.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @geraldarthur. Do you know why i am not able to export mbtiles from imported Mapbox map in Tilemill?

Comment: Unsure. If you ask this a separate question and provide some more details and/or screenshots, I can do my best to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design: tilemill-reference-layer only brings in tiles as a reference point, not markers.

Comment: thanks for the response ! is there any way to get markers from custom hosted map into tilemill ?